# Scala anonymous type constraint

Tags: scala, inheritance, types, anonymous, traits

I am given an abstract syntax tree which I cannot modify:

```
trait Expr
case class Equals(lhs: Expr, rhs: Expr) extends Expr
case class Plus(lhs: Expr, rhs: Expr) extends Expr
case class Id(value: String) extends Expr
```

Now I would like to create a converter, but this fails:

```
trait Converter[T <: Expr]
trait BinaryConverter[T <: Expr with { def lhs: Expr; def rhs: Expr }] extends Converter[Expr] {
  ???
}
```

But this does not work. If I remove `Expr with`, then it compiles. Same if I remove `with { def lhs: Expr; def rhs: Expr }`.
What should I do to make it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the correct syntax:

```
trait BinaryConverter[T <: Expr { def lhs: Expr; def rhs: Expr }] extends Converter[Expr]
```

Comment: Incredible. Thanks for sharing this. I never saw anywhere on the internet.